# how to hide java 11 Nashorn deprecation warnings

Tags: java, gradle, javac, java-11, nashorn

I recently upgraded to Java11. There are 150 new Nashorn deprecation warnings:

```
Utils.java:31: warning: [removal] NashornScriptEngineFactory in jdk.nashorn.api.scripting has been deprecated and marked for removal
            NashornScriptEngineFactory  factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
```

Is it possible to hide these deprecation warnings?

What I've tried:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += '-Xlint:-deprecation'
}

./gradlew build -Dnashorn.option.no.deprecation.warning=true

gradle-wrapper.properties: org.gradle.jvmargs= -Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning
```

as well as

```
NashornScriptEngineFactory  factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ENGINE = factory.getScriptEngine(new String[] {"--no-java --no-deprecation-warning"}, null, className -> false);
```

I believe [JDK-8210140](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210140) may reference a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning that you are seeing is emitted by the compiler, the `--no-deprecation-warning` only suppresses the runtime warning `"Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release"` that is emitted when creating the script engine instance.

You should be able to use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("removal")
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
```

In the source code to suppress the warning completely.

Or otherwise use:

```
-Xlint:-removal
```

As a compiler argument. This will suppress the warnings, but you'll still get a note on a per file basis.

Comment: Now NashornScriptEngineFactory itself is deprecated.